# using DRF with an other authentication backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, keycloak

i am using keycloak as IAM for my project which is a multi service project.
i want to use django rest framework for my django service.
i have managed to make authentication work and request.user returns an instance of User from django.contrib.auth.models, the problem is drf creates a new request object for the view, and the user authenticated by keycloak backend set in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS is lost,
to solve this problem i have made a permission class like the following:

```
class ClientRoleBasedPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    role = "create_room"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if self.role in request._request.user.get_all_permissions():
            return True
        return False
```

i am using this simple view to test things

```
class ListUsers(APIView):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    * Only admin users are able to access this view.
    """
    permission_classes = [CreateRoomPermission]
    permission = "create_room"

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
        usernames = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
```

authentication backend i am using :[KeycloakAuthorizationCodeBackend](https://github.com/moezF/django-keycloak/blob/master/src/django_keycloak/auth/backends.py)

is there a better way to solve this issue ?

Comment: show source of your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`

Comment: updated with link to the authentication backend